# How to put a div always below a absolute position div that have dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, layout, css-position

I have these layouts:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id="contentwrap">
         <div id='content'></div>
         <div id='lhs'></div>
         <div id='rhs'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#content {
    margin: 0 300px auto 180px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 142px;
}    

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#lhs {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
}
#rhs {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

only 1 requirement: #content must be the first element inside the [contentwrap].

Its height is dynamic.

Now I have problem when its height increases: the content will overlaps with my #footer.

[image: My current layout]
How do I make sure the '#footer' is always appear below the '#content' and no overlapping happened ?

P/S: Sorry for the tiny image, imgur did that !

Comment: Is there any reason you define **position:absolute** to your content DIV?

Comment: Not really, just for CSS layout. Since I need to render #content first, so I put my CSS like that. Is there away without absolute-position, to still keep my HTML, and achieve the layout ? Actually I have left, right and content (which is center)

Comment: You don't show any styling for footer, rhs, lhs - do you have any defined? Also what is the layout you are trying to achieve? Sometimes a little more information goes a long way.

Comment: I just added, P/S: is there a solution without Javascript involved ?

Comment: That's better, but what is your footer class?

Comment: Nothing special for #footer, I included :)

Comment: Thanks for the reponses so far, but all are not really my expected answer - either involve JS or not really working !

Answer (score 0):

Auto push footer after updating the content:

```
<style>
#content {
    margin: 0 300px auto 180px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 142px;
    background-color:red;
}    

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer{
    position:absolute;
}
</style>

<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id="contentwrap">
         <div id='content'>
             Example Text<br>
             Two Lines
         </div>
         <div id='lhs'></div>
         <div id='rhs'></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">The is the Footer</div>
</div>
<script>
function updateFooter(){
footer=document.getElementById('footer');
content=document.getElementById('content');
contentBottom=content.offsetTop+content.offsetHeight;
footer.style.position='absolute';
footer.style.top=contentBottom + 'px'
}
window.setInterval(updateFooter,100)
</script>
```

Comment: Nah thanks for that but I can't use polling. I already think about that. Is there away to do it without JS ?

Comment: Can you change the DOM, or just CSS?

Comment: I can change the DOM but #content must be the first element in the <contentwrap> so that it get rendered first, reason being it's for Google bot to scan it first. And I prefer no JS involved

Comment: And can you change the #content to relative isntead of absolute?

Comment: yup I can, but then the layout will be out of place ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this uses a technique where all 3 columns are floated left so that they stack up next to each other, and a negative left-margin is used to pull the left-hand column back into view.

I've not tested this extensively (just Firefox 18 / Windows7), so it may not behave on all browser/OS combinations:

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#contentwrap {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 300px auto 170px !important;
}    

#lhs {
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    margin-left: -100%;
}

#rhs {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#footer {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've just tested this in IE6 / IE7 and it works fine - how is it broken for you in IE7?

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way. But that does not mean that its the right/safe way. This example is only a demonstration that it is possible and I am encouraging you to modify your html and **NOT** use this technique. Use

```
<div id='lhs'></div>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id='rhs'></div>
```

Along with `float: left;`

This example uses calc() function from css3, so it might not work in older browsers. Although this is working and is responsive(will change width according to page width) you should modify your html as I see no reason as to why "content" has to come first.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QE2G5/)

Comment: I have to put #content first, not #lhs.

Comment: #content has to be the first, as for SEO. Google bot will scan our content to rank our page. It's a 'must' requirement.

Comment: Did you see the fiddle link that I attached? It has content first and then lhs followed by rhs. This is the only possible way I know of. Note: I have given the width of div's in percentage. You can change it as you would like.

Comment: :( I need to support IE7+, FF12+ as well. Thanks for calc(). It seems this problem : <content> must appear first, is a real headache

Answer (score -2):

you can use the style `max-height` on the #content div

or place an empty div between footer and content like this:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id="contentwrap">
         <div id='content'></div>
         <div id='lhs'></div>
         <div id='rhs'></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;height:0px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
    <div id='footer'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: content DIV have position:absolute. So, there is no need to use clear:both.

Comment: If position is set to absolute and content is dynamic, then there is no way that I see with which you can avoid it overlapping the footer. One has to set it to relative. But it would be great if you could prove me wrong, coz we all are learning here.